# how to get rid of exceed matrix dimension (binning data)?

Tags: matlab, binning

```
bet{j,3} = react{j};
numBins = {};
edges = linspace(min(bet{j,3}), max(bet{j,3}), numBins(bet{j,3}));
[N, whichBin] = histc(bet{j,3}, edges);
binsize = NaN*zeros(size(bins));

for k = 1:numBins
       bin = find(whichBin == k); 
       binMembers = bet{j,3}(bin);
    if (~isempty(bin))
       mu(k) = mean(y(bin));
    end 
end
```

error on 
`edges = linspace(min(bet{j,3}), max(bet{j,3}), numBins(bet{j,3})); that says it exceeds matrix dimensions`
 Any suggestions to what could be the problem, as well as suggestions if this is code might work for binning data (e.g., reaction time)?

Comment: `numBins = {}; ... numBins(bet{j,3})...` this looks suspect. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your line `numBins = {};` creates an empty cell array. But in `numBins(bet{j,3}));` you are trying to access an element. As there is none it fails on `index exceeds matrix dimension`.